# how to add keycloak module to openshift wildfly cartridge?

Tags: openshift, wildfly, keycloak

I'm using a wildfly 10 cartridge on openshift on line and want to protect the application using a keycloak wildfly adapter. I add the adapter modules to the .openshift/config/modules in my local git directory and I modify the .openshift/config/standalone.xml (as specified in the documentation [here](https://developers.openshift.com/servers/wildfly/deployment-options.html)). Unfortunately when I add/commit/push my project the result is that remote standalone.xml is correctly updated but the adapter module files are not there. What am I doing wrong?